# React native expo ejected ios lottie error on build

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios, lottie

I been working on a react native app using Expo.
After I did most of the code, I found some short comings with expo, so I need to do some bare bone work to get some of the futures of the app to work. so I ejected it.

everything works fine. build it on android and deployed on my own device.
But the IOS part of the project is giving me some problems. Whenever I try to build it, I'm getting a "abort trap:6 " error. When I looked in the log, I can see is something to do with the Lottie for react native. (I am going to attach the whole log in this thread.)

The did the ejecting by doing a "expo eject" after wards I went to the IOS folder and did a pod install (With no errors)
From what I can see on the lottie-react-native GitHub page, this is the only step required to get it working with bare workflow.

I am at a lost, hoping someone out there can point me in the right direction.
Thanks for your time,

```
MergeSwiftModule normal arm64 (in target 'lottie-react-native' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -merge-modules -emit-module /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AnimationViewManagerModule\~partial.swiftmodule /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ContainerView\~partial.swiftmodule -parse-as-library -disable-diagnostic-passes -disable-sil-perf-optzns -target arm64-apple-ios12.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk -I /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native -I /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-ios -F /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native -enable-testing -g -import-underlying-module -module-cache-path /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity\=checked -Onone -D DEBUG -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-ios/Lottie.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React/React-Core.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/lottie_react_native/lottie-react-native.modulemap -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native/include -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/lottie-react-native -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBLazyVector -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBReactNativeSpec -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTRequired -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG\=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -target-sdk-version 14.5 -emit-module-doc-path /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/lottie_react_native.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/lottie_react_native.swiftsourceinfo -emit-objc-header-path /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/lottie_react_native-Swift.h -module-name lottie_react_native -o /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/lottie_react_native.swiftmodule

<unknown>:0: error: fatal error encountered while reading from module 'lottie_react_native'; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project
<unknown>:0: note: module 'lottie_react_native' full misc version is '5.4.2(5.4.2)/Apple Swift version 5.4.2 (swiftlang-1205.0.28.2 clang-1205.0.19.57)'

*** DESERIALIZATION FAILURE (please include this section in any bug report) ***
could not deserialize type for 'ContainerView': top-level value not found
Cross-reference to module 'lottie_react_native'
... RCTView

Please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project and the crash backtrace.
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend -frontend -merge-modules -emit-module /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AnimationViewManagerModule~partial.swiftmodule /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ContainerView~partial.swiftmodule -parse-as-library -disable-diagnostic-passes -disable-sil-perf-optzns -target arm64-apple-ios12.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.5.sdk -I /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native -I /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-ios -F /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native -enable-testing -g -import-underlying-module -module-cache-path /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -Onone -D DEBUG -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods -enable-anonymous-context-mangled-names -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-ios/Lottie.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React/React-Core.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -Xcc -fmodule-map-file=/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/lottie_react_native/lottie-react-native.modulemap -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/lottie-react-native-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native/include -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/lottie-react-native -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBLazyVector -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FBReactNativeSpec -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTRequired -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCTTypeSafety -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-RCTText -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Documents/Apps/myappPlay-3/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -Xcc -I/Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -target-sdk-version 14.5 -emit-module-doc-path /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/lottie_react_native.swiftdoc -emit-module-source-info-path /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/lottie_react_native.swiftsourceinfo -emit-objc-header-path /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/lottie_react_native-Swift.h -module-name lottie_react_native -o /Users/remotebuild/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-bsngomtsyoidpohclqtguvhmwcuw/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/lottie-react-native.build/Objects-normal/arm64/lottie_react_native.swiftmodule 
1.  Apple Swift version 5.4.2 (swiftlang-1205.0.28.2 clang-1205.0.19.57)
2.  While evaluating request ASTLoweringRequest(Lowering AST to SIL for module lottie_react_native)
0  swift-frontend           0x0000000108bb86e0 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 52
1  swift-frontend           0x0000000108bb7858 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 128
2  swift-frontend           0x0000000108bb8cb0 SignalHandler(int) + 292
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x0000000189cf5c44 _sigtramp + 56
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib  0x0000000189cadc24 pthread_kill + 292
5  libsystem_c.dylib        0x0000000189bf5864 abort + 104
6  swift-frontend           0x00000001053ecfc8 swift::ModuleFileSharedCore::~ModuleFileSharedCore() + 0
7  swift-frontend           0x0000000105392528 swift::ModuleFile::readParameterList() + 0
8  swift-frontend           0x00000001053da580 swift::SILDeserializer::readVTable(llvm::PointerEmbeddedInt<unsigned int, 31>) + 2144
9  swift-frontend           0x000000010544dcc8 swift::SILDeserializer::getAll(bool) + 92
10 swift-frontend           0x0000000104ed2ee4 swift::ASTLoweringRequest::evaluate(swift::Evaluator&, swift::ASTLoweringDescriptor) const + 7852
11 swift-frontend           0x0000000104fa1bd8 swift::SimpleRequest<swift::ASTLoweringRequest, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> > (swift::ASTLoweringDescriptor), (swift::RequestFlags)9>::evaluateRequest(swift::ASTLoweringRequest const&, swift::Evaluator&) + 216
12 swift-frontend           0x0000000104ed6548 llvm::Expected<swift::ASTLoweringRequest::OutputType> swift::Evaluator::getResultUncached<swift::ASTLoweringRequest>(swift::ASTLoweringRequest const&) + 756
13 swift-frontend           0x0000000104ed36f0 swift::performASTLowering(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::Lowering::TypeConverter&, swift::SILOptions const&) + 124
14 swift-frontend           0x0000000104af792c swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 6484
15 swift-frontend           0x0000000104a8c460 main + 1136
16 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000189cc9f34 start + 4
error: Abort trap: 6 (in target 'lottie-react-native' from project 'Pods')
```

Comment: Were you abel to solve this??Getting this same error on my side

Comment: Nope. never got it to work. was thinking about doing a clean install without going with expo. just a bareboned one. but never got around to try it.